# AuthZForce-PEP-IDM Always allow access even when user doesnt have permission for specific resource

Tags: fiware, authzforce

I created user and gave him only one role.(Member)
Currently this role doesn't have any permission with any Http verb nor path.
This is my user:

```
{
organizations: [1]
0:  {
website: ""
description: "AREAS"
roles: [1]
0:  {
name: "Member"
id: "09dc1bdba42c48de9e15e88816284cbc"
}-
-
enabled: true
id: "363ac390cfc94aa293e02547afa78256"
domain_id: "default"
name: "AREAS"
}-
-
displayName: "root"
roles: [0]
app_id: "aea8f4a70b87422cb48068db9f0c6aea"
email: "root"
id: "root"
}
```

Now, when i try to do GET request on address: http://localhost/parameters/search_tables/
for which this user don't have permission,
it allows me access and redirects me nonetheless.
This is log from pep proxy:

```
2015-11-13 14:55:53.446  - INFO: IDM-Client - Checking token with IDM...
2015-11-13 14:55:53.484  - INFO: AZF-Client - Checking auth with AZF...
2015-11-13 14:55:53.484  - INFO: AZF-Client - Checking authorization
to roles [ '09dc1bdba42c48de9e15e88816284cbc' ] to do  GET  
on  parameters/search_tables/ and app  aea8f4a70b87422cb48068db9f0c6aea
2015-11-13 14:55:53.508  - INFO: Root - Access-token OK. Redirecting to app...
Refused to set unsafe header "accept-encoding"
Refused to set unsafe header "cookie"
```

My config file regarding authorization is:

```
config.azf = {
        enabled: true,
    host: '192.168.4.180',
    port: 8080,
    path: '/authzforce/domains/afb096b2-8951-11e5-980f-6bf3c4dac98a/pdp'
};
config.public_paths = [];

config.tokens_engine = 'oauth2';
```

My Pap policy is:

```
 <PolicySet PolicySetId="default" Version="1.0" 
PolicyCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.1:policy-combining-
algorithm:ordered-permit-overrides">
<Target />
 <Policy PolicyId="permit-all" Version="1.0" 
 RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.1:rule-combining-
 algorithm:ordered-permit-overrides">
<Target />
<Rule RuleId="permit-all" Effect="Permit" />
 </Policy>
 </PolicySet>
```

How should i formulate my PAP policy to enable authorization level2, to use only http verb and resource path for authorization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Authzforce PAP permits all when no policy is added. Check if your PAP has the right information:

```
GET
/domains/{domainId}/pap/policySet
```

Edit 1:

In order to be able to connect with Authzforce, you need to configure some Authzforce parameters into your IdM instance:

- `ACCESS_CONTROL_URL` at `fiware-idm/horizon/openstack_dashboard/local/local_settings.py`
  and
- `ACCESS_CONTROL_MAGIC_KEY` at `fiware-idm/horizon/openstack_dashboard/local/local_settings.py`

Then, just go to IdM, and check that the permissions and roles are well configured. Sometimes, you have to 'trigger' the policy generation in IdM by going to your application -> manage roles and just click 'save' to trigger the XACML generation.

Comment: Yeah it seems my policy is permit all.What should my policy look like if i want to use level 2 authorization(Only http verb and resource path)

I edited my question to insert my pap policy xml

Comment: With creating roles is not enough, you need to add permissions to each resource you want to protect. With no permissions, there won't be any XACML (as there are no resources to protect)- I'm supposing you are using IdM for role and permissions management.

Comment: Ok, i created permission GET on /parameters/search_tables/ path, and gave this permission to admin role.
Now i tried to access this resource: http://localhost/parameters/search_tables/    with user that does not have admin role:
     
and it is still allowing me. 
Is there some additional step?

Comment: Is this permission appearing in the Authzforce PAP? If not, somehow IdM is not being able to PUT the XACML into the Authzforce PAP

Comment: Yeah when i check pap policy on http://192.168.4.180:8080/authzforce/domains/afb096b2-8951-11e5-980f-6bf3c4dac98a/pap/policySet

it still says permit all.
Is there some configuration for authzforce where i have to point to my idM?

Comment: Did you configure Authzforce parameters in IdM? otherwise it will never know where to `PUT` the policies. In the file `fiware-idm/horizon/openstack_dashboard/local/local_settings.py` you should modify the `ACCESS_CONTROL_URL` value, and also in `fiware-idm/horizon/openstack_dashboard/local/local_settings.py` the `ACCESS_CONTROL_MAGIC_KEY` parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95054/discussion-between-albertinisg-and-milos-miletic).